# getMonth() in Javascript from format dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: javascript

I have a date in format dd/mm/yyyy and when I try to use `getMonth()` I get the dd field.
For example if I have "01/12/2019" it will take 01 as month instead of 12. Is there a way to get the month from this format?

This is my code:

```
var beginDate = document.getElementById("beginDate").value;
var month = new Date(beginDate).getMonth();
```

inside `beginDate` there's `"01/10/2019"` (October 1st 2019)

Comment: Show the code you're trying so we can understand how you're calling it

Comment: @DarrenSweeney edited with code

Comment: `const month = beginDate.trim().split("/")[1];` where `trim` is not that really necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com)

```
const beginDate = "22/05/2019"

const date = moment(beginDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY');

const month = date.format('M');

console.log(month)

//05
```

Comment: can you please share the output as well.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know Moment.js, very helpful.

Comment: Glad to help :D

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use any external libraries like momentjs or datejs. Try this it may solve your problem now.

```js
const date  = "01/12/2019";
const split = date.split('/');

console.log('day', split[0])
console.log('month', split[1])
console.log('year', split[2])
```

```js
var date = moment('01/12/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
console.log(date.month()+1);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it easy.
You don't need external libraries:

```
var beginDate = "01/10/2019";
var timeZone = 'your time zone'; //en-GB etc...
var month = new Date(beginDate).toLocaleString(timeZone , {month: "2-digit"}); //month = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get months using `getMonth()` as shown below, But here `0=January, 1=February etc.`

```js
var date = "05/12/2019"
var d = new Date(date);
var n = d.getMonth();
console.log(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need some external library to do this task. You should use javascript date object to get it done easily, `getMonth()` returns month indexed from `0` to `11`. Prefer javascript always instead of unnecessarily importing external js files for libraries

```
var beginDate = document.getElementById("beginDate").value;

let reg = /(\d\d)\/(\d\d)\/(\d+)/gi;
const[date,mon,year] = reg.exec(beginDate).splice(1);       
month = new Date(year,mon-1,date).getMonth(); // months are indexed from 0 to 11 for jan to dec
console.log(month); // 0 for jan and 11 for dec
```

Answer (score 0):

Month in javascript is 0 indexed that mean `0` represent January, So you need to add 1 to get the month correctly

```js
function getMonth(dt) {
  let splitDt = dt.split('/');
  return new Date(`${splitDt[2]}-${splitDt[1]}-${splitDt[0]}`).getMonth() + 1;
}

console.log(getMonth("01/10/2019"))
```

```css
1st oct
```